# How to get SharePoint hyperlink column type with MsGraph

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have a SharePoint list with a Hyperlink/Picture column.

When I try to get all columns from the list with

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/MySubsite:/lists/<mylistguid>?$expand=columns
```

I get just following result for the hyperlink column

```
    {
        "columnGroup": "My Columns",
        "description": "",
        "displayName": "Picture",
        "enforceUniqueValues": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "id": "2222eeee-5555-4444-3333-aaaaabbbbbbb",
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "Picture",
        "readOnly": false,
        "required": false
    },
```

The result set of this column does not have any information about the column type. But all other columns have a specific property which identifies their type.

Is this a bug or something coming in future?

Edit: As this feature is currently missing, I added a UserVoice entry here. Please vote if you also need this feature.
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32827402-support-for-sharepoint-hyperlink-or-picture-field

Comment: how about using `$expand=fields` ?

Comment: @GautamSheth $expand=fields does not work on lists, just on single list items. Also I want to get the type of the field not the field value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official Graph API documentation, not all Sharepoint Field types are represented in the API at this time

> Note: These properties correspond to SharePoint's SPFieldType enumeration. While the most common field types are represented above, this beta API is still missing some. In those cases, none of the column type facets will be populated, and the column will only have its basic properties.

Taken from:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/resources/columndefinition.md

You can open a github issue with them at that link and try to get it resolved that way.  At this point it looks like it is not available.